# mpld3.show displaying blank html

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

My code runs good with no errors displayed. But when it opens the browser it gives me a blank page.
Can you help me in this?

It imports data from Excel. Eg.
Names
Michael
Adam
Andrew
Adam
Michael

It takes the count of each name that is repeated, and displays a bar chart.
Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3

data = pd.read_excel (r'Sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sample1')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Names'])
mydata = [df.groupby('Names').size()]


df['count'] = df.groupby('Names')['Names'].transform('count')

df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)

ax = df.plot(x='Names', y='count',color='blue',label='count',kind='bar')

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))

fig_size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]

fig_size[0] = 20
fig_size[1] = 25
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = fig_size
print ("Current size:", fig_size)

plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('Graphicalrepresentaion.png')

fig = plt.figure()

mpld3.show(fig=None, ip='127.0.0.1', port=8888, n_retries=50, local=True,    
open_browser=True, http_server=None)`
```

Whats Working - 
It opens up the browser with blank page.
plt.show()
 - works too , displays accurate graph of the values